# how do i get radio button value in ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

here is my search button in php file. I don't know how to link the radio button to the js file.

```
<button id="submit">Search</button>
```

this is where in js file starts

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function link_events() {
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", showFile, false);
xhr.open("GET", "un.xml");
xhr.send();
}
function showFile() {
var outstring = "<table><tr><th>Name</th><th>Population</th><th>Area</th></tr>";
var i;

if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200){
   var countries = xhr.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("country");
}
```

}

Comment: you need to show us the radio button HTML code at leas, and what you tried so far

Comment: Here is my html <form name="continent">
 <input type="radio" name="continent" value="Africa"> Africa </input> <br 
         />      
 <input type="radio" name="continent" value="Australia/Oceania"> 
        Australia/Oceania </input><br />
 <input type="radio" name="continent" value="Europe"> Europe</input>. 
          <br 
          />
         <button id="submit">Search</button>
          </form>
  
<div id="outarea">

Answer (score 0):

The html syntax in your form is not correct. It should be like this:

```
<form name="continent">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="continent" value="Africa">
        Africa
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="continent" value="Australia/Oceania">
        Australia/Oceania
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="continent" value="Europe">
        Europe.
    </label>
    <br/>
    <button id="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

You can use Jquery to get value of selected radio and [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to submit form.

Add this code below  tag:

```
<script>
    const myForm = $('form[name="myForm"]');
    myForm.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form
        // Get value of selected radio
        let dataFormRadio = $('input[name="continent"]:checked').val();
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "/your-url.php",
            data: {continent: dataFormRadio}
        })
            .done(function (res) {
                console.log('request successful')
            })
            .fail(function (res) {
                console.log('request failed')
            });
    });
</script>
```